# NSString - 2 digit number

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, nsstring

`Hi,
i have a string with a 2 digit numbers (like 32) but i want to get and use it as 2 single digit number (like 3 and 2). how can I do it? thanks in advance.

```
  NSString *depositOverTotalRwy = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [deposit text]];
NSArray *components = [depositOverTotalRwy
                       componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
NSString *firstThird = [components objectAtIndex:0];
unichar firstChar = [firstThird characterAtIndex: 0];
NSString *firstCharStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", firstChar];

unichar secChar = [firstThird characterAtIndex: 1];
NSString *secCharStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",secChar];






NSLog(@"%@ over %@", firstCharStr, secCharStr);

if ([firstCharStr  isEqualToString: @"1"]) {
    firstCharStr=@"wet";
    NSLog(@"wet");
}
if ([firstCharStr  isEqualToString: @"2"]) {
    firstCharStr=@"snow";

    NSLog(@"snow");
}
if ([firstCharStr  isEqualToString: @"3"]) {
    firstCharStr=@"ice";
    NSLog(@"ice");
    }

if ([secCharStr  isEqualToString: @"1"]) {
    secCharStr=@"wet";
    NSLog(@"wet");
}
if ([secCharStr  isEqualToString: @"2"]) {
    secCharStr=@"snow";

    NSLog(@"snow");
}
if ([secCharStr  isEqualToString: @"3"]) {
    secCharStr=@"ice";
    NSLog(@"ice");
}

NSString *secThird = [components objectAtIndex:1];
if ([secThird isEqualToString: @"1"]) {
    secThird = @"wet";
    NSLog(@"wet");
}
if ([secThird isEqualToString:@"2"]) {
    secThird = @"snow";

    NSLog(@"snow");
}
if ([secThird isEqualToString:@"3"]) {
    secThird = @"ice";

    NSLog(@"ice");
}

NSString *thirdThird = [components objectAtIndex:2];

if ([thirdThird isEqualToString: @"1"]) {
    thirdThird = @"wet";
    NSLog(@"wet");
}
if ([thirdThird isEqualToString:@"2"]) {
    thirdThird = @"snow";

    NSLog(@"snow");
}
if ([thirdThird isEqualToString:@"3"]) {
    thirdThird = @"ice";

    NSLog(@"ice");
}

dep.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1/3 %@%@ 2/3 %@ 3/3 %@", firstCharStr,secCharStr, secThird, thirdThird];
```

it works now with to digits (ie 32) but if i try to put just one digit I get an error.... any idea? thanks

Comment: Whatever you do, check to make sure the string actually contains nothing but digits first....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using xcode, how do you split NSString into component parts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942263/using-xcode-how-do-you-split-nsstring-into-component-parts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through and extract one character at a time from your string.

```
for(int i = 0; i < [myString length]; i++)
{
      char extractedChar = [myString characterAtIndex:i];

      if(extractedChar == '1')....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

NSString's `-characterAtIndex:` should do the trick:

```
NSString            *firstThird = @"32";
unichar             c1, c2;

c1 = [ firstThird characterAtIndex: 0 ];
c2 = [ firstThird characterAtIndex: 1 ];

switch ( c1 ) {
case '3':
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Skipping any unicode complexities, how about extracting the characters

unichar firstChar = [firstThird characterAtIndex: 0];

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *firstThird = [components objectAtIndex:0];//--- I get 32 from this string but i want 3 and 2
NSArray *numbersAsStrings = [firstThird componentsSeparatedByString:@""];
NSMutableArray *digits = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *digit in numbersAsStrings)
{
    [digits addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[digit intValue]]];
}
```

This sample can take any number and convert it into an array of `NSNumber`s.

Access:

```
int int1 = [[digits objectAtIndex:0]intValue]; //returns 3
```